# Show map in image view

Tags: android, imageview, openstreetmap

I have made an app which shows the user current location using the OpenStreetMap. I used the osmdroid library. Now I want to show this map in an image view in another app. Any ideas on how could I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: See my updated post, It will help you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your get map as Image, You have to follow some steps

1. You have to create project on Google Developer Console
2. Activate your API keys in your library dashboard on developer console.

**Use this URL for Activate static map page API:**

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/static_maps_backend/overview?project=YOUR_PROJECT_NAME

3. If you need to get map us static image and without any marker then call this following web link

   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=roadmap&center=12.990912,%2080.218304&zoom=17&size=640x400&key=YOUR_API_KEY

This link is given output like this

[image]

4. If you need to get map us static image and with some marker then use this [link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=roadmap&center=12.990912,%2080.218304&size=640x400&markers=color:red%7Clabel:A%7C12.992227,%2080.217629&markers=color:green%7Clabel:B%7C12.988619,%2080.216777&key=YOUR_API_KEY)

This link is given output like this

[image]

5. If you need more than 2 markers then you have to append more marker information and lat, long

Hope this will help you...

If need more information visit here

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/styling

Answer (score 1):

Find the solution

This URL gives the map image based on latitude and longitude values

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318
&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284
&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

For more details find the url : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro